# VS2019 Latest Update: constexpr: "expression did not evaluate to a constant" for FIXED string array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr

<sup>*Note: There are a number of questions on Stack Overflow with very similar-looking titles, but none that I have found is actually a duplicate, IMHO.*</sup>

I have been using code like the following in my project(s) for a number of years, without problem. However, since a recent update to Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.2 - though it *may* have been at 16.7.1), the **MSVC** compiler has started to generate the error shown (I have the compilation 'Standard' set to C++17).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { }
    static constexpr char Letters[6][10] = { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot" };
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) std::cout << f.Letters[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error (at the opening brace in the `constexpr` line):

> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>  message :
> failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol

The **clang-cl** compiler continues to accept the code without any warning.

I have a fairly 'trivial' fix for this issue, as below:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { }
    inline static const char Letters[6][10] = { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot" };
};
```

However, I am intrigued by the error report. Is there something I am missing (and have been missing for ~5 years), or is this a bug in the latest release of MSVC? If the former, what is my error or invalid assumption?

Comment: Probably a bug. msvc 19.24 accepts this with c++17 enabled.

Comment: Yes it is a bug, and MS is "investigating this issue". Some people also mentioned, that it helped to add a `;`.

Comment: @FabianKeßler Adding the semicolon where? This *could* be an answer - with a link to the MS report, possibly.

Comment: This here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unexpected-error-c2131-expression-did-not-evaluate/1343697

Comment: Re the MS report linked by @FabianKeßler _"...A fix for this issue has been released!  Install the most recent release  ..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten I have installed many updates to the latest release since that comment was made ... but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm now using VS 2022 Version 17.5.3 (late March, 2023) and the problem/bug persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid (and accepted by GCC and Clang), and this is indeed a bug in MSVC v 19.27 and above. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rdnn9M8j3

The bug was reported on January 26, 2021:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Compile-error--when-declare-static-const/1320740
and is currently under investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the bug-report link: I looked for one but failed to find it. That, alone, is sufficiently 'authoritative' for me to accept your answer.