# constexpr std::max on MSVC fails if passed initialization list is maped as a symbol (constexpr)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, constexpr

### Background

Big C++17 project which is build for multiple platforms. Have to support MSVC, clang and gcc

### Problem

Following code fails on MSCV and it is fine for other compilers.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

#define FOO_1 1
#define FOO_2 2
#define FOO_3 3

class Baz {
  static constexpr auto data = {FOO_1, FOO_2, FOO_3};
  static constexpr auto copy_max = std::max({FOO_1, FOO_2, FOO_3});
  static constexpr auto data_max = std::max(data);

  void bar(std::initializer_list<int>);

  void test();
};

void Baz::test()
 { bar(data); }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7nv3z3rMY

`FOO_x` macros comes for external library. `Baz` is my code.
Now I need `data_max` for some logic and I whish to calculate that at compile time.

As a workaround I've introduce `copy_max` which is initialized by duplicate code which is bad (there are lots of values and list can be changed), also `data` are used in runtime code.

Apparently problem is present only for msvc 19.29 (installed on my machine) older version do not have this issue.

### Question

Is there a way to somehow overcome this problem without using extra macros or duplicating code? I've try to use `std::max_element`, which is constexpr since C++17, with same outcome.
Is this a know bug or should I file new one?

Comment: Looks like the same (or similar) problem I reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63558400/10871073). Using `inline static const auto data_max = std::max(data);` appears to fix the issue.

Comment: Is this similar to: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c51e7f0f32dc95c

Comment: Alternative (smaller) [mcve] https://godbolt.org/z/sjW1f63xn

Comment: And, using the fix in my earlier comment, you can still have a line like `constexpr auto goo = data_max;` in a `Baz` member function.

Comment: If you  make `data` a `std::array`, and then use `std::max_element` it works  https://godbolt.org/z/s9zxYK5KP

Comment: @Kaldrr yes this is a good idea. I had to rewrite some code which was using explicitly `std::initializer_list` (like `bar`), but this was not a great effort. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that bug was fixed in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Fail-to-evaluate-valid-constant-expressi/1622722

But if one still needs a workaround for an older version of Visual Studio, then it is possible to use an extra constructor of `std::initializer_list<T>` present in MSVC:

```
    constexpr initializer_list(const _Elem* _First_arg, const _Elem* _Last_arg) noexcept
        : _First(_First_arg), _Last(_Last_arg) {}
```

to construct `std::initializer_list` from an array:

```
#include <algorithm>

// standard approach, but does not work in MSVC before v19.36
constexpr std::initializer_list<int> a{ 1, 2, 3 };
constexpr auto amax = std::max( a );
static_assert( amax == 3 );

//workaround for MSVC before v19.36
constexpr int x[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
constexpr std::initializer_list<int> b( x + 0, x + 3 );
constexpr auto bmax = std::max( b );
static_assert( bmax == 3 );
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7MhznGd66