# MSVC bug when initializing a constexpr variable via constexpr constructor that accepts a raw array reference?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The following code compiles fine when using the latest GCC & Clang stable versions.

However MSVC gives an error that the initialization of the matrix does not evaluate to a constant. Is this a MSVC bug or do I miss something?

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAKwAnKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEAf6kAA6oCoRODB7evgHBaRmOAuGRMSzxif7JdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BQbaY9sUMjc0EpdFxCUm2TS1teZ0KE4MRwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOYAzBHI3lgA1CZ7bqIKSi3n2CYaAIL7h8eYZxfIs8QRwHcPzzMBwYRy8p3Obic30wrH%2BTxeILeHzcXkctEIAE84YDgaDwRdZlhVNsUgRsQCAPQUgC0tLp9IZjKZzJZrLZ7LZlIpJ2%2BXgcJyIJ3iJyYsXoAtQJ2ImAImwYIpODDw21oGMVrEw6BOKSYeGIAIBvP5ESJAH0CCcaMxaAaAOxWJ4nJ0nNAMWaYVQpYgnE0e80QFYfAAiJywVCYXloZL2DsezpdAndnu9vtU/tdsx5BHQIBAGQAXphzVLSAm3RbCbmC0WLchAyAAfH48RUAB3Ez2/W2oOkRtNp1oG320zdvtOjux%2BMdoMG%2BEaQKVvN4QvFlvt%2B3T86xh4L7NV5c1hNDqyjmN2mdnuePKkc293%2B8P29chVmLUsJgEH6qE6t4hMFIpAkLoGNcpatoQCA8qgbAJiwKR0O8jgwVQXggr0YiYlys6PAQmBwQYuEQgQGKAcwMHEYB5qlou1arm2CimgAbtRe5LiutaeO0DGMdiRxMNcJzvp%2BeBphaVpiHasYpF4YrKg2V47h6KTosghBlkmXqCR%2BX7pomFoUTWEDmAAbIxYheJgCgrCY/gWGu3E2TOtmDlxTGOdZc6BBOs5efO/DEBANEHnRrbBicGhblKbbIlFrYOTGZyWNYa4eXG/ZnBujrpfG/mBaxtEcbQYURQlg4xS5vjxRYiVWJYg6pdlU6ZWljVNiwTHmZZNl2W2jndYOjlhWZ3hdbZa59c5nh9ZeLWNZuWX9vNzzzktPkZrhyY%2BgwZoWsAMqmqmpr%2BR1I0QOtAokTWJknMNFmButPneZ5O7%2BSceU5mxh5rsVkXfRCsVVTVyVtqlO5g81YMrX5JBvUF7FHj9pWeOVnGVW5CXWNY9WPVDXkQ7jkOBHgVBve1t2jT17b%2BE5FgDdTwbnCG5OgwTBP475HOE9KsrEPKh0WhOa6kANp7bqznOjs9bMzlLeMy8tHMEAg32LhEw14OgprNMAPiMAQRlmGY5OKqgYkbNtW0isQf5Yob1kzeD8trXpSnehGgqoIBf5EPqtmOWdelZh9BWxfdemPezO7c3KiXGWTnUKN143U91EUpw7K2S8t2dengZm4fJCsGcW8cjYnY30W5KeTbkbpVzOG6i%2BeW7YTej7tx3ness%2BESZBh%2BYflkZxXutrtacJonj1%2BklPQrE4nFwAAcpZ7MEJyBFwpYbxlPYR9Vxm2qWJx7Efa%2BBP4O%2B9s99onMZa/H6WxnL%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%2BjDHGI4AU4ygkFBpJulk8huTMwQFMcCmwJxcCEBhvsb%2BHhknxOsVwFYvB7F9JWGsBAMIsCJADKQFxexbQeP0JwaF6z/AhIlbwKVgTgmhItaQCJ0SNgEGkgQcglBGlxOJSEfAPs9D8HOaIcQ1yk23JUOoPpgrMDCtIL%2Bf8GytE6N8dmqVLTUThpOKgEmMq5UKsYkqlVFo1WxJSca01AatCWtINapgtrKDFu8bwD1Xq/G%2BtsP6813bnEgCdS6rxexS2SoCV2xxrqOBmGXT61d0713DLKXCyQQA%3D):

```
<source>(72): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(71): note: failure was caused by out of range index 4; allowed range is 0 <= index < 4
```

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

struct index_t final
{
    constexpr index_t() = default;
    constexpr index_t(const std::size_t r, const std::size_t c) :
        row{ r },
        col{ c }
    {
    }

    std::size_t row{};
    std::size_t col{};
};


template<typename type_t, std::size_t rows_v, std::size_t columns_v>
class matrix_t final
{
public:

    explicit constexpr matrix_t(const type_t(&values)[rows_v][columns_v])
    {
        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows_v; ++row)
        {
            for (std::size_t col = 0; col < columns_v; ++col)
            {
                m_values[row][col] = values[row][col];
            }
        }
    }

    constexpr index_t get_index_for_value(const type_t& value) const
    {
        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows_v; ++row)
        {
            for (std::size_t col = 0; col < columns_v; ++col)
            {
                if (m_values[row][col] == value)
                {
                    return index_t{ row,col };
                }
            }
        }
        throw std::invalid_argument("value not found in array");
    }

    constexpr auto operator[](const std::size_t row) const
    {
        return &m_values[row][0];
    }


private:
    type_t m_values[rows_v][columns_v]{};
};


// Intialization of matrix : error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
// message : failure was caused by out of range index 4; allowed range is 0 <= index < 4
constexpr matrix_t matrix   
{ {
    { 18, 39, 91, 91 },
    { 67,  3,  9, 95 },
    { 69,  3, 68, 93 },
    { 69, 21, 92, 92 }
} };

int main()
{
    static_assert(matrix[1][1] == 3);
    static_assert(matrix.get_index_for_value(68).row == 2);
    static_assert(matrix.get_index_for_value(68).col == 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's the same (or related) bug as I reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63558400/10871073). Harder to work round, in this case, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yup its a bug : https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Incorrect-Index-Out-of-Range-Error-in-Co/1161104?entry=problem&ref=native&refTime=1631981283477&refUserId=2fefbb59-d415-4992-98ed-af90606e46d9 Should have looked there first.

Answer (score 2):

The bug has been confirmed here [Incorrect-Index-Out-of-Range-Error](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Incorrect-Index-Out-of-Range-Error-in-Co/1161104?entry=problem&ref=native&refTime=1631981283477&refUserId=2fefbb59-d415-4992-98ed-af90606e46d9)