# C++20 constexpr vector and string not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, constexpr, stdstring

I'm getting a strange compiler error when trying to create `constexpr` `std::string` and `std::vector` objects:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::string cs{ "hello" };
    constexpr std::vector cv{ 1, 2, 3 };
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains that "the expression must have a constant value":

[image: compiler error]

Am I missing something? I am using the latest Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 version: 16.11.4, and the reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) states that `constexpr` strings and vectors are supported by this compiler version:

[image]

I have also tried the `constexpr std::array`, which does work. Could the issue have anything to do with the dynamic memory allocation associated with vectors?

Comment: Did you try to actually compile it? The message comes from Intellisense, which may not have caught up with the latest compiler features.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Are you talking about the C++ Language Standard option? If yes, it is set to ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20).

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I did try, and it throws 2 errors for each object instantiation: "error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant", followed by "xmemory(1341,38): message : failure was caused by allocated storage not being deallocated".

Comment: [Possibly related/same bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63558400/10871073)? However, I tried your code in VS-2019 using the clang-cl compiler and get similar errors. (Maybe clang-cl doesn't yet support C++20?)

Comment: @AdrianMole That is probably correct, the reference does specify that constexpr vectors and strings are not supported by clang.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your program is actually ill-formed, though the error may be hard to understand. `constexpr` allocation support in C++20 is limited - you can only have *transient* allocation. That is, the allocation has to be completely deallocated by the end of constant evaluation.

So you cannot write this:

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

Because `v`'s allocation persists - it is non-transient. That's what the error is telling you:

```
<source>(6): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(6): note: (sub-)object points to memory which was heap allocated during constant evaluation
```

`v` can't be constant because it's still holding on to heap allocation, and it's not allowed to do so.

But you *can* write [this](https://godbolt.org/z/P7x4Y1x6Y):

```cpp
constexpr int f() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    return v.size();
}

static_assert(f() == 3);
```

Here, `v`'s allocation is transient - the memory is deallocated when `f()` returns. But we can still use a `std::vector` during `constexpr` time.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tested with a `constexpr` function and it does seem that the vector is allocated at compilation time.

Comment: The example with constexpr f() doesn't compile either: variable ‘v’ of non-literal type ‘std::vector’ in ‘constexpr’ function.

Comment: @mentalmushroom It does (there's even a link). Your compiler either isn't new enough to support constexpr allocation or your standard library doesn't support constexpr vector yet. The latest gcc, clang, and msvc all support it: https://godbolt.org/z/PGKnbehqq

Answer (score 6):

As @barry explained, you cannot create variables which requires dynamic allocation and which will be still available at runtime. I believe that this is explained by the following exclusion in :

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:

https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.17

> a new-expression ([expr.new]), unless the selected allocation function is a replaceable global allocation function ([new.delete.single], [new.delete.array]) and the allocated storage is deallocated within the evaluation of E;

Still you can do amazing things with this new features. For example join strings:

```
constexpr std::string join(std::vector<std::string> vec, char delimiter) {
  std::string result = std::accumulate(std::next(vec.begin()), vec.end(),
    vec[0],
    [&delimiter](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
      return a + delimiter + b;
    });
  return result;
}

static_assert(join({ "one", "two", "three" }, ';') == "one;two;three"sv);
```

Comment: Hi! :) Looks cool, but  i don't succeed to reproduce your code: https://godbolt.org/z/K7KbEWW4Y