# C++ 20 constexpr vector not working in gcc 10

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I was reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498591/11673310) about `constexpr vector` in C++20, where the poster gave this code

```cpp
constexpr int f() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    return v.size();
}

static_assert(f() == 3);
```

which he asserts is correct under C++20. He also gave [this](https://godbolt.org/z/P7x4Y1x6Y) successfully compiled (in MSVC v19) Godbolt snippet.

However as I change the compiler to gcc 10 (which is supposed to support C++20 and  constexpr container), compiler emits error messages complaining roughly about `vector<int>` being *non-literal type* because it does not have `constexpr` destructor.

This kind of compile error persist to gcc 11, though. In gcc 12.1, it compiles successfully.

Having browsed the gcc 12.1 changes history, I  found out this seemingly relevant change

> Several C++23 features have been implemented
>
> - ...
> - [P2242R3](https://wg21.link/p2242), Non-literal variables (and labels and gotos) in constexpr functions ([PR102612](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR102612))

My questions are:

1. `vector` do have a `constexpr` destructor since C++20 right? (see [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/%7Evector)) Why does gcc before 12 complains as not?
2. Whether the above code is strictly legal under C++20? Which one of MSVC or gcc is not standard conformant?
3. TBH I'm not in the stage to fully understand the proposal. Can you explains what it is about? Which problems does it try to solve?

Comment: The relevant change is [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/1ae8edf5f73ca5c3bf132cc52825dc1f709499dd). That is, only gcc12 supports `constexpr` vector. The P2242R3 you mentioned does not make much sense here.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Does it mean the compiler support for `constexpr` container at [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#:~:text=constexpr%20container%20operations) is wrong? Cause I was using it as the reference.

Comment: P2242R3 is only relevant with `if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {`, when you have variables conditionally depending on whether something is constant evaluated or not. That is not the case in your example.

Comment: Support for C++20 is ongoing in compilers and you might find missing or incomplete things, especially the older the compiler you test is. If something isn't working in gcc 11 but works in gcc 12.1 then assume it has been implemented or fixed since gcc 11 was released and move on.

Comment: I think the link to cppref says support for constexpr std::vector is in GCC 12.

Comment: @Masquue You are wrong, because the "`constexpr` container operations" proposal P0784R7 mentioned in your link does not make changes to `std::vector`. [P1004R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1004r2.pdf) is the correct paper.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, sir. You are right! Damn it, there are just so many entries in that table and I was searching using the wrong term.

Comment: I 100% concur.  There are a lot of entries, and it is not always clear what the brief description refers to.  Compiler support for C++20 for many compilers is still a "work in progress", with plenty of gaps.