# constexpr specifier on std::vector doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++20, constexpr

**Edit**: This now errors on godbolt ([gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/8T5qaqE3v), [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/E5qnsoeoE)) with non-empty initialization. There was some confusion because my msvc was erroring with empty initialization when godbolt wasn't (probably because my msvc is more recent).

```cpp
#include <vector>

constexpr std::size_t f() {
    constexpr std::vector<int> v{ 1 };
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto a = f();
}
```

With `/std:c++latest`

> ConsoleApplication9.cpp(12,24): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
> ConsoleApplication9.cpp(12,24): message : (sub-)object points to memory which was heap allocated during constant evaluation

**Edit**: gcc warning with non-empty initialization explains the problem

> error: 'std::vector(std::initializer_list{((const int*)(& const int [1]{1})), 1}, std::allocator())' is not a constant expression because it refers to a result of 'operator new'
> 195 |             return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n));
> |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~

Comment: VS tells me `/ZI` is for edit and continue which is disabled..

Comment: @RichardCritten You link to `/Zl`.

Comment: The problem is that [constexpr allocation support in C++20 is limited - you can only have transient allocation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498591/12002570). This means that you can't have `int main(){constexpr std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};}` but can have `constexpr int f(){std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3}; return v.size();}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::vector` shouldn't have had the `constexpr` specifier https://stackoverflow.com/a/69498591/11998382. The following works

```
constexpr std::size_t f() {
    std::vector<int> aaa{};
    return 1;
}
```

<strike>I think godbolt was wrong to compile this.</strike> (if you never allocate then its okay) `constexpr` functions can evaluate at runtime, but the `std::vector` can't be `constexpr` in the runtime version of this function

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Both GCC, Clang, and MSVC on Godbolt accept your code. I don't see why `constexpr` wouldn't be allowed on that variable. The linked answer says it's forbidden to preserve an `std::vector` from compile-time to runtime, but you're not doing that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if the function was executing at runtime, then with the `constexpr` specifier the `std::vector` would be preserved from compile to runtime. Well that was my thinking. But the GCC and Clang compiler implementers know more than me so ...

Comment: I'm talking about preserving its memory (the elements). E.g. making the vector a global `constexpr` variable and computing the elements at compile-time. Since the variable would still exist at runtime, that would be an error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat so I was right, but only when something is actually allocated on the vector

Comment: What? Your case is different: the vector is either used entirely at runtime or entirety at compile-time, both are fine.