# Why is `constexpr vector` not allowed to allocate in `consteval` function?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

**4th Edit**: the original question title is:

> Why `constexpr` specifier is not allowed for non-empty `std::vector`?

This title, as @Barry points out, is a duplicate to [C++20 constexpr vector and string not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498115/c20-constexpr-vector-and-string-not-working). But there is a difference in my question description: I am allocating `constexpr vector` in **`consteval` function** instead of **normal runtime function or `constexpr` function**.

I understand that **during compile-time computing, only transient allocation is allowed**, as @Barry answered in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498115/c20-constexpr-vector-and-string-not-working).

What I was confused about is that: for `consteval` function:

1. any of its local variables will be dealloacted after it returns
2. it only returns in compile-time, since it will only be called in compile-time
3. so `constexpr vector`, as a local variable, will be deallocated in compile-time
4. then why is it not allowed?

And my **other edits** below answered this confusion.

**-----------------Below is the orignal question description----------**

Why the following code does not compile:

```cpp
consteval int foo() {
  constexpr std::vector<int> vec{1};
  return vec[0];
}
```

As I learned, `std::vector` and `std::string` can be used in compile time as long as both the allocation and deallocation happens in compile time. And if I delete the `constexpr` specifier, this code will compile.

But adding `constexpr` still does not violate this rule, right? Why is it not allowed?

I got this error when compiled with gcc 13 but I don't understand it:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/allocator.h:195:52: error:
'std::vector<int>(std::initializer_list<int>{((const int*)(& const int [1]{1})), 1}, std::allocator<int>())' is not a constant expression because it refers to a result of 'operator new'
  195 |             return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n));
      |
```

**Edit**:
My question is not a duplicate to any other questions. There is only one duplicate [constexpr specifier on std::vector doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944248/constexpr-specifier-on-stdvector-doesnt-work?rq=2), but with wrong answer about why `constexpr` is not allowed: it states that "compile-time `std::vector` should be allocated and deallocated in compile-time, so it is not allowed", but the code above does not violate this rule.

**2nd Edit**:
Thanks for answers from @user4581301 and @chris. I learned that I got a wrong understanding of a rule:

> **Wrong**: it will be fine if memory allocated via `new` in **compile-time** is `delete`d also in **compile-time**.

> **Correct**: in compile-time, memory allocated via `new` must be `delete`d in the same **constant expression context**.

And the answer to my question is that `constexpr vector<int>` will introduce a **new constant expression context** while `vector<int>` does not.

**3rd Edit**: [What are the conditions that `constexpr` will start a new constant expression context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76775335/what-are-the-conditions-that-constexpr-will-start-a-new-constant-expression-co)

Comment: You have to read between the lines a bit. After `constexpr std::vector<int> vec{1};` a dynamic allocation, the one inside `vec`, would still be alive after the constant expression, and that's a no-no.

Comment: @user4581301 But `std::vector<int>` is a local variable, it will be deallocated when it goes out of scope, right? And it cannot be alive in any run time context since it is `consteval` function.

Also, even without `constexpr`, it is still dynamic allocation, why does it compile without `constexpr`?

Comment: `vec` is automatically allocated, but it contains inside it a pointer to a dynamically allocated array (and a couple book-keeping variables). that internal array must not exist after the constant expression, `constexpr std::vector<int> vec{1};`, but there it is still alive on the next line at `return vec[0];`.

Comment: @Waker, Making the variable `constexpr` starts a new context. It's this context that the allocation escapes. Picture (conceptually) the compiler spinning up a new interpreter for evaluating a `foo` call, and then spinning up another new interpreter from the first one for the `constexpr` line. If you remove the `constexpr`, you're still in the first interpreter.

Comment: Regardless, great question. One of those rare duplicates deserving of an upvote. May it live long as a useful landing page.

Comment: Another question deserves creating a new **Ask Question**.

Comment: Note the bit about how new and delete are handled that marcinj's discussing in their answer in the duplicate has moved from `[expr.const]`/5.17 and 5.18 to [`[expr.const]`/5.18 and 5.19](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.18)

Comment: Yeah I'm rolling back your edits - this question *is* a duplicate of the linked question (it's asking why you can't just declare a `consetxpr vector` that does allocate something), and the answer is the answer to your question - your code does violate the rule, there's no deallocation.

Comment: @Barry Hi Barry, glad to see you response to my question. But I think you did not read my question carefully, in your linked question, `constexpr vector` allocates in `main` function, and I understand that it will definitely fail to compile since the memory allocated in compile time is not deallocated also in compile time.
But in my example code above, I allocates `constexpr vector` in a `consteval` function, which will never runs in a run-time context. And I think since it is a local variable in the `consteval` function, it will get deallocated when the function return.

Comment: @Barry I admit that the title of my question should be more specific, it indeed looks like a duplicate, I should ask "Why `constexpr` specifier is not allowed for non-empty `std::vector` in `consteval` function?"

Comment: @Barry And I also understand that I can just use `vector` here since even if I can declare `constexpr vector` I cannot modify it since it is `const`, while with just `vector` I can use and modify it in compile time. I am asking this question just with the purpose of understanding a language trick here. And the edits you rolled back answered my confusion.