# What are the conditions that `constexpr` will start a new constant expression context?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, constexpr-function

I asked a question in [Why `constexpr` specifier is not allowed for non-empty `std::vector`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774877/why-constexpr-specifier-is-not-allowed-for-non-empty-stdvector?noredirect=1#comment135351283_76774877) previously, after finding the answer, I have another question here.

I tested and found that it is valid to dynamically allocate memory in one `constexpr` function and free it in another `constexpr` function (via `new` and `delete`), so a `constexpr` subroutines does not introduce a new context:

```cpp
constexpr int* bar() {
  return new int{2};
}

constexpr int foo() {
  auto ptr = bar();
  int val = *ptr;
  delete ptr;
  return val;
}

constexpr int i = foo();  // OK
```

Then I get another question, what are the conditions such that `constexpr` will start a new context?

In a constant expression context (like in a `consteval` function), why `constexpr std::vector<int>` will start a new constant expression context (which make it invalid to declare because the memory allocated through `new` will escape this context) while `std::vector<int>` does not allocate memory in a new constant expression context?

I am a new learner about `constexpr` and C++20, please point out if I get wrong assumptions or ask a wrong problem.

Comment: Handy, if more than a little inscrutable, reading: [expr.const](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const).

Comment: Wouldn't `delete [] ptr;` be correct?

Comment: @Retired Ninja  Are you referrring to the example code in the question? I used `new` to allocate an `int`, not array `int[]`, so I used `delete ptr` here. And I also tested that modifying the above code to be `new int[]{1,2,3}` and then `delete[] ptr;` also works.

Comment: `int{2}` looks visually more similar to `int[2]` than `int(2)`.

Comment: Been tripped up by that visual similarity more than once.

Comment: Yep, looked like `[2]` and not `{2}` to my old programmer eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are the conditions such that constexpr will start a new context?

Being a constant expression.

The initializer for a `constexpr` or `constinit` variable *is* a constant expression. The initializer for a template parameter *is* a constant expression. The expression in an `if constexpr` *is* a constant expression. These expressions begin constant expression contexts.

Calling a `constexpr` function is not a constant expression. Calling a `constexpr` function *while evaluating a constant expression* happens within a constant expression context, but it is not a context by itself.

Calling a `consteval` function is not itself a constant expression context, but you're not allowed to call one unless you're already within a constant expression context.