# How to get random access container with std-ranges at compile time?

Tags: c++, constexpr, std-ranges, c++23

I have the following code:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

auto func(const char* Str) {
    return std::string_view(Str) 
        | std::views::split(',')
        | std::views::transform([](auto inp) { return inp.data(); })
        | std::ranges::to<std::vector<const char *>>();
}
```

*Note* I know that the result of `func(test)`, where `test = "a,b"` would be to pointers pointing into `test` and thus printing them would result in `["a,b", "b"]` but I am only concerned with the beginning of the string anyways.

I tried to make this function `consteval`, as i saw that all the `std::ranges` functions are all`constexpr`. This was my attempt:

```
template<const char * Str>
consteval auto func() {
    return std::string_view(Str)
        | std::views::split(',')
        | std::views::transform([](auto inp) { return inp.data(); })
        | std::ranges::to<std::vector<const char *>>();
}
```

But I get the error ([See demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YsYdWr5Kf))

> error: call to consteval function 'func<test>' is not a constant expression
> note: pointer to subobject of heap-allocated object is not a constant expression

where `test` is a "string" of type `static constexpr char[]`. I know that this error stems from `std::vector` allocating memory, but I thought `std::vector` supports `constexpr`. Though maybe it is the problem of `std::ranges::to` which does not treat the destination container type as `constexpr`.

I have also tried to use `std::ranges::to<std::array>` but `to` did not support that either. Is there another container which supports random access and `constexpr` which works with `std::ranges::to`?

Comment: Because this is still not transient, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498115/c20-constexpr-vector-and-string-not-working. You can still do `static_assert(func<test>().size());` though.

Comment: I see, `std::array` does not allocate heap memory but is not supported by `ranges::to`. Is there another container which might be suitable?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't seem to relate to the body of the question. The title says you get "different results" with and without `constexpr` - but the actual issue is that when you declared the function `consteval`, using the function became ill-formed. I suppose "ill-formed" is a different result, but it'd be nice if the question title were more specific to the issue at hand.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, when I started the question, I was still getting `invoke_result_t<...>` returned from the function instead of a vector because I used only `constexpr`. But writing down the question made me realized some problems which I fixed and thus changes the question but forgot to update it. Fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the transient dynamic allocations into a static/automatic allocation, taking advantage of the fact that `vector_returning_function().size()` can be a constant expression (because the vector dies and returns its memory):

https://godbolt.org/z/MKser4ses

```cpp
consteval auto vector_to_array(auto f) {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = f().size();
    return [f]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) mutable {
        return std::array<std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(f())>, size>{{ f()[I]... }};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}
```

You call it with a captureless lambda that returns the vector instead.

Comment: This is an excellent example of the use of constexpr vector, i.e. using a vector that is constructed and destructed at compile time.
Seems this should be the expected answer, just to emphasize a bit more the point in the code, adding `static_assert` on the return value: [https://godbolt.org/z/1ecaT8MdM](https://godbolt.org/z/1ecaT8MdM).